# How set value into a function in the element of javascript Object?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have this code:

```
this.mGroupFunctions={};
        for(var i=0; i<cols.length; i++){
            var col=cols[i];
            this.mGroupFunctions[col]=function(oContext) {
                var name = oContext.getProperty(col);
                return {
                  key: name,
                  text: name
                };
              };
        }
```

If I debug it i obtain 
[image]

where into a function I insert col and not the value of variable col!!!

How can I resolve my problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the function runs, the variable `col` no longer contains the value that it had when the function was created. You can use an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) to create a closure that captures the value of `col` for each iteration in the loop:

```
this.mGroupFunctions = {};
for(var i=0; i<cols.length; i++){      

  this.mGroupFunctions[cols[i]] = (function(col){

    return function(oContext) {
      var name = oContext.getProperty(col);
      return {
        key: name,
        text: name
      };
    };

  })(cols[i]);

}
```

Comment: whit your code I have an error: `Cannot set property 'COD_ARTICOLO' of undefined ` in the `row this.mGroupFunctions[col]=function...`.
I'm confused...

Comment: @bradipo: Right, `this` inside the IIFE is not the same as outside... You can return the function from the IIFE and add the returned value to the object. I updated the code above.

Comment: I have a problem.. if I try to see mGroupFunctions afrer the "for" I have a object with only one element:
`undefined: function (oContext) {`

Comment: @bradipo: My bad, the `col` is undefined outside the IIFE, use `cols[i]` there.